# Error lvalue required as left operand of assignment c++

Tags: c++, if-statement, conditional-statements, lvalue

The whole program basically just allows the user to move the cursor and if the user is in the given range of coordinates (2,2), the user is allowed to type the input. I have just provided some bits of the code which I thought would be enough for solving the problem.

I don't know what is causing this problem.Can you also explain why is it happening !!

```
void goToXY(int ,int);
```

Created a function with two ints.

```
int X = 0, Y = 0;
```

Initialised two ints.

```
if(X = 2 && Y = 2){
    cin >> input;
}
```

This is where the error is(it's above)

```
void goToXY(int x = 0, int y = 0) {

    COORD c;
    c.X = x;
    c.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), c);
}
```

Here's where I define the function(it's above)

Comment: Prepare a [MCVE] that reproduces the error please.

Comment: `if(X == 2 && Y == 2){`

Comment: To clarify Bo's comment a bit. Your `X=2` tries to assign the value 2 to X and not compare it to 2. You have to use `==`

Comment: Also default values should not appear in the functionn definition unless you have a inline function:: `void goToXY(int x , int y) {`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in this if statement

```
if(X = 2 && Y = 2){
    cin >> input;
}
```

The condition is interpretated like

```
if(X = ( 2 && Y ) = 2){
    cin >> input;
}
```

I think you mean

```
if(X == 2 && Y == 2){
    cin >> input;
}
```

Take into account that it is better to include default arguments in the function declaration instead of the function definition because usually it is the declaration that is visible in a compilation unit.

For example

```
void goToXY( int = 0, int = 0 );
```

Also you may redeclare the function in a block scope supplying another default arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with:

```
if(X = 2 && Y = 2){
    cin >> input;
}
```

Since you are using the wrong operator(`=`, not `==`), then the precedence of `2 && Y` becomes more. This is evaluated as:

```
if(X = (2 && Y) = 2){
    cin >> input;
}
```

Which, if true, would simplify to:

```
if(X = true = 2){
    cin >> input;
}
```

Which doesn't make sense because of `true=2`. Fix the code to:

```
if(X == 2 && Y == 2){
    cin >> input;
}
```